# Error in MySQL to HiveQL Conversion including DATE_SUB and INTERVAL

Tags: mysql, hive, hiveql

I am trying to convert the query written in MySQL to HiveQL
The part of query giving me error is :

```
 WHERE 1 = 1
 AND table1.incoming_date >= DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL DAY(CURDATE()) - 1 DAY),INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
```

Most probably it is because INTERVAL is not supported in Hive with DATE_SUB().
So, can someone convert this part for me.

Error:

```
ParseException: 
extraneous input 'DAY' expecting {')', ','}(line 179, pos 60)
```

Comment: Please **always** show us the errors

Comment: Included the error

Comment: hive version please?

Comment: It is PySpark 3.0.0
Using it inside spark.sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you can do this using a combination of [Hive date functions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions) `date_sub` and `add_months`.

```
beeline> select current_date today, add_months(date_sub(current_date,1),-3) past_date;
INFO  : OK
+------------+-----------+
|   today    | past_date |
+------------+-----------|
| 2020-08-13 | 2020-5-12 |
+------------+-----------|
1 row selected (0.101 seconds)
```